# What type of bug/insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I found this bug on the bedsheet and can’t figure out what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the size of that insect as well as a geographical location and season?

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like a webspinner, Order Embioptera. But many geographic locations would rule that out. I have never heard of these entering homes. I can assure you that it is not a bedbug.

Comment: Using my browser's zoom function to magnify the photo we have lets me confirm the order as given (and as the animal has wings, we can be pretty sure it's a male); going to family might be possible for Gina if she still has the specimen, but identification further than that may not be possible -- turning a search engine loose on the order name and "Ross" will (I believe) eventually turn up a notice to the effect that the specialist just named has over 1000 species not yet formally named in his collection ...

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a species of [earwig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig). I get them inside my house at certain times of year or after it rains. As far as I know all species are harmless but I would double check that.

Comment: Could you please explain, why you think this was an earwig? For example, the wings of earwigs in my area have quite degenerated wings, not such prominent ones as in the given picture. But this might be different for other species. Would be nice, if you could clarify this.